# Current and voltage sources

Tags: current-source, source

What happens when a current source is connected in series with a voltage source? I mean to ask, what will the current be through the series combination and voltage across it?

Is it allowed to make such a connection?

Comment: When the irresistable force meets the immovable object ... you are reminded that in the real-world, these idealised abstractions are not useful in the edge-cases. Releasing the magic smoke is permissible but unadvised.

Comment: Ok. i take that as it is not possible.

Comment: I consider it poetry.

Answer (score 3):

The current flowing will be the current of the current source.  You need to add a load to close the loop before you can see what the volatage will be.  The voltage will be your current source times your load impedance.  E = I*R  The voltage across your current source will be I*R minus your voltage source in series.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following ideal circuit.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fFRQdx.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

There is 1A of current through the voltage source (using the [passive sign convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_sign_convention)) and -1V across the current source.

The current source supplies power to the voltage source (if the voltage source were a battery, the battery would be *charging*).

It's a perfectly valid circuit and, given the wire across the pair of sources, the voltage across the pair is 0V.

If there were a resistor R across the pair instead of a wire, the voltage across the pair would simply be the voltage across the resistor:  \$1A \cdot R \$

Problems arise when connecting current sources in *series* or connecting voltage sources in *parallel*.  Then, unless the sources are identical, you can end up with nonsense like \$1A = 2A \$ or \$2V = 3V\$.